# Handling Child Data with Microservices

Tags: angular, rest, .net-core, architecture, microservices

I'm trying to figure out the best way to organize my code in a new projects. I'm taking a microservices approach with a .NET Core API and an Angular UI.

I need to wrap my head around the following example:

I have a parent level entity, Invoices. There's an Invoices table in my database, and I'm building an Invoices service in the API that will handle the CRUD.

Each invoice has a one-to-many relationship with InvoiceDetails, which provides a deeper level of info about the Invoice.

I'm planning on keeping InvoiceDetails CRUD in the same InvoicesService listed above, as in my head it all rolls up to that service.

This seems straight-forward enough, but I'm torn on the UI side of things. When I create my Invoice, I need to then also create the InvoiceDetails. Should I make one call to the API to create the invoice, then upon the return make another to create the InvoiceDetails, or should this all be handled in one call?

Is there a better way that I should be thinking about this? I'm trying to separate concerns as much as possible, so it seems like there should be one API controller for Invoices that handles the CRUD and a separate controller for InvoiceDetails.

Answer (score 1):

I think your API should have an endpoint for creating an Invoice containing a list of InvoiceDetails objects. At the same time there should also be available endpoint to create a single InvoiceDetail object in your API. Think Rest API in this case and not very tight to the needs of a single angular/react/vue,..etc client application.

This will make sure there is flexibility in your API in case you will need UI for adding extra InvoiceDetails to an existing Invoice or a new full Invoice object with all the InvoiceDetails objects.

Which of those endpoints you use should be decided by the UI or any other client. E.g creating a new Invoice in UI I would go for create Invoice endpoint with a list of InvoiceDetails. Adding InvoiceDetails to existing Invoice I will use endpoint for adding InvoiceDetails object.

This is a more case by case evaluation based on what one is trying to achieve in the UI. UI can add a parent with all their childrens or add a child to an existing parent.

**NOW OVER TO HOW TO TALK WITH THE API FROM UI(ONE OR SEVERAL CALLS)?**

Having several API calls from UI to add one and one InvoiceDetails object when creating an Invoice can be an issue of synchronization between the UI and API. Let us say you succeed adding 7/10, but not the rest 3 because something goes down, then you maybe need retry policy and keep a state of which was a success or not to present in UI? What about performance?

I would recommend one API call when creating an "Invoice" object, that will either succeed or fail and easier to control the communication between UI client and API.

Comment: what about the scenario where I'm creating an Invoice, but I don't yet have the InvoiceDetails and will be creating those after creating the Invoice?

would I just reference the CreateInvoiceDetailsService from inside the CreateInvoiceService? I'm trying to minimize my dependencies.

Comment: If your list of InvoiceDetails objects are empty when creating an Invoice then you simply don't call the InvoiceDetailsService. If the InvoiceDetails objects are not empty then you pass the list to a method in your InvoiceDetailsService. That method will have the responsibility to add them. You are minimizing your dependencies and are separating concerns when letting InvoiceDetailsService handle their entity and InvoiceService handle their entity.

Comment: @halterdev Make sense? :)

Answer (score 1):

From a Domain Driven Design perspective, this would depend on what is the Entity/Aggregate in your business domain. At present, InvoiceDetails sound like a Value object that requires no identity of its own, which suggests that it does not need its own CRUD Web APIs.

One way to look at this question is to ask ourselves whether it makes sense to have the InvoiceDetails exist on its own. Does it make sense for InvoiceDetails to be created without being tied to any Invoice? If yes, then it is probably wise to have a separate API endpoint to manage the InvoiceDetails resource. If not, then what are the justifications to create another endpoint for InvoiceDetails?